# Is there any standard for colors of Serial Peripheral Interface wires?

Tags: spi

Having DuPont cables like on the picture...

[image: DuPont cable coloured -- for what I have in hands.]

... and the RFID RC522 reader with colored wires as found in one of the tutorials.

[image: Colors on pins]

I know that copper is the same inside of the wires. Anyway, **is there any standard or de-facto standard of assigning colors to the meaning of the pins?** Black for ground and red for +voltage are known from elsewhere. But what about all the other pins? Here is the detail view for better readability:

[image: Colors and pins.]

Comment: Nope, there isn't., except for black for GND and red for Vcc, but even these are just conventions.

Comment: btw: do you wire this for SPI or for I2C? for SPI don't wire SDA and for I2C don't wire MISO and MOSI.

Comment: @Juraj I2C. The SPI was just example. The question was meant to be more general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no standard. However:

- Red is often +5V
- Black is often GND
- I often assign colours numerically according to the resistor colour code:

  - 0 - Black
  - 1 - Brown
  - 2 - Red
  - 3 - Orange
  - 4 - Yellow
  - 5 - Green
  - 6 - Blue
  - 7 - Purple
  - 8 - Grey
  - 9 - White

You may have noticed that that's the same order they appear in the cable too, which is helpful. It's handy when working with things like 8 bit data buses, since you can then easily identify which wire is which.

In some disciplines there are standards, like for audio ***r**ed is **r**ight and left is white* (that's the little rhyme I use to remember), and of course there's regulations defining colours for mains cables, but for this kind of thing just use whatever makes sense to you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience.